# How can I protect items stored outdoors?

Tags: outdoor, protection, cover

Because of space limitations in our apartment, we need to store some items in the terrace. It is basically suitcases, baby stroller and box of books. There is a ceiling, so it wouldn't rain on it, but we are concerned about the cold, humidity, etc. We live in NY: cold winters, hot summers.

What would be advisable to create a good layer of protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temperature is probably not a problem for the types of items you describe (assuming none contain any liquids). That is a good thing since it would be extremely difficult or expensive to keep them from the extremes in summer and winter in the northeast.

You should try to avoid extreme moisture changes. That means sealing in water impermeable containers. You might look at the large plastic bins offered in the big box stores, The edges can be sealed with duct tape (masking tape will dry out and crack). Larger items could be stored in plastic bags.  The construction grade trash bags are stronger than regular bags.  The tops can be knotted and then sealed with duct tape.

You might also consider putting in packets of dehumidifying materials.  These will absorb any existing moisture and help of there is a minor leak in the bags or bins.

These covering will also help keep snow out, but it would be good to arrange so that drifting snow does not sit on the items for a long time. If that were a risk, you might consider a small tarp (the blue/brown/silver plastic types) to put over the whole stack.  Shake snow off after the fall.

Comment: +1, water is your enemy here, not temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Rubbermaid makes [storage sheds](http://www.rubbermaid.com/Category/Pages/SubCategoryLanding.aspx?SubCatId=HorizontalSheds&CatName=Outdoor) and [deck bins](http://www.rubbermaid.com/Category/Pages/SubCategoryLanding.aspx?SubCatId=DeckBoxesPatioBenches&CatName=Outdoor) that will easily fit on a terrace.  These will protect most from the elements and keep things looking tidy. Books and clothes that you wish to store in the shed you might want to give them another layer of protection.  As for things that might freeze, keep them in the house.

Comment: That's what I use. And I put Damprid tubs in them too.